# Android: Populating a listview from MySQL database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, listview

I have some data from mysql which I'm retrieving from my phone app. What is the best way to populate a listview with multiple data? I have something simple like this:

```
try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        int jArrayLength = jArray.length();
        List<String> listContents = new ArrayList<String>(jArrayLength);

        for(int i =0; i<jArray.length(); i++){

            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            listContents.add(json_data.getString("full_name"));

        }

        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.front_page_listview);
        myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listContents));

    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error parsin data "+e.toString());
    }
```

I can add the names just fine, but what if I want more information within that same row? ie: email, birthday, etc...

```
listContents.add(json_data.getString("full_name"),json_data.getString("email"));
```

Gives me errors.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think listviews can have "columns" so you should concatenate the strints instead. Like:

```
listContents.add(json_data.getString("full_name")+ ' ' +json_data.getString("email"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Define arrayadapter

```
           ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            String fullName;
```

Then get value via http and set on array adapter(a1) :

try{

```
                    jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject json_data = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                        targetamount=json_data.getString("full_name");

                        al.add(fullName); 

                    }
                }
```

Now excuted event:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {  
                 this.progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                try{
                         ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
                        this.progressDialog.dismiss();  
                         listview.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(DemoActivity.this,al.toArray(new String[al.size()])));

                    }
                    catch(Exception e){

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 

            }
```

want more info about this problem related then goto belows link:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database
and
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/